# ¿Còmo acceder a una pagina web mediante distintos equipos, pero con la misma red

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tenemmos 6 computadoras, lo que queremos hacer es abrir nuestra pagina web en todos los equipos que poseemos, pero sin instalar ningun programa, nuestro proyecto es crear una pagina web y dentro de ella meter un formulario; el cual consulte, registre y actualice datos.

Y estamos viendo en donde podemos guardar nuestra base de datos (ejemplo: MySql)

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a S.O. en español. Te invito a leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Además, te invito a realizar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Cuando te refieres página web, imagino que tienes un servidor web donde alojar dicha página. En cuanto a la base de datos, tienes muchas opciones. Me parece que sería bueno que fueses más específico en tu pregunta, sino no podremos ayudarte y puede terminar cerrada. Saludos.

Comment: Saludos bro, bienvenido a SOes, te recomiendo que vayas por https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso obtengas tu primera medalla. Revisa también cómo realizar preguntas en: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , si es una intranet, necesitas que haya un servidor o alguna máquina que vaya a estar encendida 24/7/365 que contenga algún servidor web, que tenga una IP estática y que sea de acceso compartido. ¿Has revisado en youTube?

Comment: Eviten poner negativos por las siguientes razones: Es usuario nuevo, tiene 1 punto, NO ha leído el recorrido. Suficiente con cerrar la pregunta.

Comment: Concuerdo con @fredyfx. Lo que el OP busca es montar una intranet. Lamentablemente esta pregunta tal cual está, no cumple con los lineamientos de la comunidad y es muy posible que sea puesta en espera o eliminada directamente. Puedes ver aquí el porqué: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions

Comment: Gracias bro, como usuarios con más tiempo, es nuestro deber formar nuevos usuarios :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mira son varios puntos a tratar
1.- La pagina web esta alojada en la pc "1" tu quieres que las demás (2,3,4,5,6) puedan acceder a ella no?, Debes en primera desactivar el Firewall de Windows, para que puedan acceder las demás pc´s
2.- Después de ello abre la consola y escribe "ipconfig" ahí te tiene que dar la ip de tu maquina.
3.- Es ip la tienes que poner en los navegadores de las demas paginas, y así estarías ingresando a "localhost" de la maquina donde tienes alojada tu web
4.- Ya solo bastaría que pusieras a ruta adecuada por ejemplo quedaría así 
192.168.1.77/Carpeta/index.php

Espero te haya resuelto tu duda saludos :D